# rSyslog stopped sending only SOME data

Tags: syslog, rsyslog

I have configured a remote logging from one of my servers to the central log server via rsyslog TCP/SSL

Everything worked fine until yesterday where most of the files just stop being transmitted while some are still sent/updated in the log server.

I have this specific config inside my /etc/rsyslog.d/

```
$ModLoad imfile    #Load the imfile input module

# poll every 10s
$InputFilePollInterval 10

# myfile
$InputFileName /var/log/data/myFile.log 
$InputFileTag myFile: 
$InputFileStateFile stat-myFile  
$InputFileSeverity Info
$InputFileFacility local3
$InputRunFileMonitor
```

when I check the file, it gets updated by my application

```
ls -la /var/log/data
-rw-r--r-- 1 adm adm  2666 Apr 22 08:52 myFile.log
```

when I try checking the establish connections from this client to my remote log server it seems to be fine (netstat -tulpan | grep syslog)

```
tcp        0      0 <clientIP>:42724       <serverIP>:10514      ESTABLISHED 31839/rsyslogd
```

however when I check the log server, I store the remote logs from clients in /var/log/remotelogs//

weirdly, some files (such as systemd.log, sshd.log, rsyslogd.log, ..) are updated correctly in real time... but myFile.log is not

```
ls -la /var/remotelogs/<clientIP>
-rw-r----- 1 root root   1945150 Apr 21 15:07 myFile.log
```

as you can see.. it stopped yesterday around 3pm my time ... wth? checking the network connection on the server too, everything seems legit ...

```
$ sudo netstat -tulpan | grep syslog
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10514           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3608119/rsyslogd    
tcp        0      0 <serverIP>:10514      <clientIP>:42724       ESTABLISHED 3608119/rsyslogd      
tcp6       0      0 :::10514                :::*                    LISTEN      3608119/rsyslogd
```

any idea what could be wrong? why some files are not being transmitted and some are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured.. a colleague of mine created a script somehow impacting those files (dunno what exactly happened) but when I disabled the script and recreated the files .. it worked like a charm again ...